# how to use html (template) file as js variable in vanila JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, typescript

usually we can write js code to assign template to variable like this;

```
var tmpl = '<div>...</div>'
```

If i introduced html template in different html file, can we import and load that (dom) file directly in js file as a variable?.
I have requirement where i have multiple html files with respective templates, And i have to get that template in js variable and load it dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course:

```
let variable;
fetch('/file/link.html').then(r => r.text()).then(t => variable = t) ;
```

Preferably you would just work with the template inside the then function instead of assigning it to a variable outside it. The reason is because you could try to use the variable before it has been set.

The alternative syntax that is more straightforward is async/await; but this is less widely supported than promises.